# Lists of list to a single list of words python

Tags: python, list

I have sentences  in the form of

```
['big', 'mistake.']
['our', 'room', 'was', 'tiny,']
['and', 'the', 'bath', 'was', 'small', 'too.']
```

How do I create a list with all the words in one list in python.

To this

```
['big', 'mistake.','our', 'room', 'was', 'tiny,','and', 'the', 'bath',...]

 t = s[1].lower().split(' ')    
 print(t)
```

Comment: Have you tried *anything*?

Comment: you can append list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a=['big', 'mistake.']
b=['our', 'room', 'was', 'tiny,']
c=['and', 'the', 'bath', 'was', 'small', 'too.']

d=a+b+c
print(d)
```

You can `+` to append one list to another ...

**Output**

`['big', 'mistake.','our', 'room', 'was', 'tiny,''and', 'the', 'bath', 'was', 'small', 'too.']`

**for multiple list**

```
 for s in newList: 
    t = t + s
 print(t)
```

Comment: I have a loop that produces these list, about 150 lists...       for s in newList:
    t = s[1].lower().split(' ')
    print(t)

Comment: @keithchingotah i have updated for multiple list you can check and tell me any problem with the code .

Answer (score 1):

`+` is the list-concatenation operator

```
list1 = ['big', 'mistake.']
list2 = ['our', 'room', 'was', 'tiny,']
list3 = ['and', 'the', 'bath', 'was', 'small', 'too.']

biglist = list1 + list2 + list3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add lists or you can use `extend` keyword

```
>>> l1 = ['big', 'mistake.']
>>> l2 = ['our', 'room', 'was', 'tiny,']
>>> l3 = ['and', 'the', 'bath', 'was', 'small', 'too.']
>>> l1+l2+l3
['big', 'mistake.', 'our', 'room', 'was', 'tiny,', 'and', 'the', 'bath', 'was', 'small', 'too.']
```

or

```
>>> l1 = ['big', 'mistake.']
>>> l2 = ['our', 'room', 'was', 'tiny,']
>>> l3 = ['and', 'the', 'bath', 'was', 'small', 'too.']
>>> l1.extend(l2)
>>> l1.extend(l3)
>>> print l1
['big', 'mistake.', 'our', 'room', 'was', 'tiny,', 'and', 'the', 'bath', 'was', 'small', 'too.']
```

Comment: This wrong, it going nested list, OP don't want nested list.

Comment: I have  a loop the is producing these list and what if there 500. How do I add all 500 of them?

Comment: @keithchingotah in that case, eigther you can use 1st method or you can iterate.. over list name to use 2nd method